# Changing the color of a single DBInspector row

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a dxDBInspector that I need to highlight one row (`edtSDate`) out of nine in green. The color properties change the colors for all rows within the inspector.

I tried:

```
edtSDate.Inspector.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
```

I also saw [How in a Delphi dxDBGrid can I change the color of a single row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925897/how-in-a-delphi-dxdbgrid-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-single-row)

But the dxDBInspector does not have OnCustomDraw / OnGetContentStyle events.

The exact component is a dxDBInspector from Dev Express, and I am on Delphi 7.

Comment: You should consult Support Center at DevExpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the variables in the `OnDrawValue` event fixed this for me. I was having trouble figuring this out because there was existing code (legacy project) that was auto assigning this event to make all inspectors match, but once I bypassed that it was simple.

All I did was assign `clGreen` to the variable `AColor` created by the `onDrawValue` event for the row.